# Why is this JavaScript function not working when the code is correct?

Tags: javascript

This code is properly written, should be working, yet it's not. I was about to make the very basics of my page, when I'd got stuck with this.

The script src command is correct as well.

Does anyone have any idea why it's not working?

```js
function continue(){
 var CM=document.getElementById("intro2");
 if(CM.style.display=="block"){
  CM.style.display="none";
 }
 else{
  CM.style.display="block";
 }
}
```

```css
#intro2{
 display:none;
 text-align:center;
 color:black;
 position:absolute;
 left:32%;
 bottom:10%;
 width:40%;
 height:35%;
 border:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="continue()" id="continue">Continue</button>

<div id="intro2">
<p><h1>text text text text</h1></p>
<a href="Page.html">Get started</a>
<img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AJLlDp1pvZTkG1K-QcKZg_Fd1eUNu-e4GKXCJOLoHA=s900-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @K.P. just a side note, you aren't allowed h1 tags inside a p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `continue` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, you can't name your function that.

Instead, use a different name like such:

```js
function doContinue() {
    var CM = document.getElementById("intro2");
    CM.style.display = (CM.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
}
```

```css
#intro2 {
 display: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 32%;
 bottom: 10%;
 width: 40%;
 height: 35%;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doContinue()" id="continue">Continue</button>

<div id="intro2">
  <p><h1>text text text text</h1></p>
  <a href="Page.html">Get started</a>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed, I basically had meant to click "Run code snippet", but clicked "Post Answer" instead. The joys of blue buttons in the same general location

Comment: Thank you for the help!
 I would've never figured it out myself